# Letters after discretionary disappear (seems an issue of package fontspec)?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, hyphenation, ligatures, discretionary

For the following case,

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
  \hsize =2in
  shelf{}ful shelf{}ful shelf\-ful di\discretionary{f-}{fi}{f\kern0ptfi}cult
\end{document}
```

I get,

[image]

Actually, if there's a `kern` followed by anything in the third argument of `\discretionary`, letters after it disappear, but when I don't use the package `fontspec`, nothing goes wrong. Is this a bug?

Comment: It's not `fontspec`. If I do the same with `xetex`, the problem shows as well.

Comment: Neat. But it is not a fontspec problem. You see the same problem if you don't load fontspec and call the font as `\font\test="[lmroman12-regular.otf]"\test`

Comment: raised as https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/137/

Answer (score 5):

This seems a bug in XeTeX. If there's something which is not a letter in the “nobreak” argument to `\discretionary` and a break is taken, the word part following the discretionary disappears.

Minimal example:

```
\input ifxetex.sty

\ifxetex
  \font\test="Latin Modern Roman:mapping=tex-text" at 12pt
\else
  \font\test=ec-lmr12
\fi
\test

\hsize =2in \advance\hsize by 11pt

shelf{}ful shelf{}ful shelf\-ful di\discretionary{f-}{fi}{f\kern0ptfi}cult task

shelf{}ful shelf{}ful shelf\-ful di\discretionary{f-}{fi}{f\/fi}cult task

shelf{}ful shelf{}ful shelf\-ful di\discretionary{f-}{fi}{f{}fi}cult task

shelf{}ful shelf{}ful shelf\-ful di\discretionary{f-}{fi}{ffi}cult task

di\discretionary{f-}{fi}{ffi}cult task

\bye
```

Compile with `xetex` and the result is

[image]

If compiled with `pdftex` we get the expected result:

[image]

Comment: The problem appears only if the `\kern` or `{}` is between two letters in the “nobreak” argument. Note also that `{}` doesn't break ligatures when an OpenType/TrueType font is used.